# How can I pass a variable between 2 activities?

Tags: c#, android, mysql, xamarin

I am using mysql to retrieve a code into my Main Activity, which stores as a string. This works, but when I try to pass it to another activity, it just wont work. I may be wrong, but I'm passing it as I would do with a regular c# variable.

Whats the correct way to pass variables (string, int) from one activity to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it this way, while passing:

```
var MyIntent = new Intent (this, typeof(MyActivity));
MyIntent.PutExtra("MyString", "This is a string");
MyIntent.PutExtra("MyInt", 20);
StartActivity (MyIntent);
```

while retrieving:

```
string MyText = Intent.GetStringExtra ("MyString");
//you get
//This is a string
int MyDefault = 0;
int MyNumber = Intent.GetIntExtra ("MyInt", MyDefault);
//you get
//20
```

Answer (score 2):

from the [Xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/):

```
   var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(Activity2));
   activity2.PutExtra ("MyData", "Data from Activity1");
   StartActivity (activity2);
```

and to retrieve the data from the second activity:

```
string text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("MyData")
```

Answer (score 1):

**FirstClass.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent (FirstClass.this, SecondClass.class);
intent.putExtra("StringData", "Stringvalue");
intent.putExtra("intData", 10);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // this line is optional. If you want to destroy FirstClass, add this line.
```

**SecondClass.java**

Add this line inside onCreate method.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
    if(i != null){
         String StringData = i.getStringExtra("name");
         int intData = i.getIntExtra("intData", 0); // second parameter is the default value. if unable to get the value of "intData", default value will parse.
    }
```

**Manifest File**

Add these line to your Manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".FirstClass">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SecondClass">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bundle object is an option too

```
public class NextActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Bundle intentBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String strResult = intentBundle.getString("strA");
}
}
```